# Minimization involving equality constraints

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to find closed form solution to following problem

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\underset{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}{\text{minimize}} \hspace{4mm}  \big(\left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(1)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2 + \left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(2)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2\big) \\
s.t \hspace{10mm}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{e_x} = 1 \\
 \hspace{17mm}\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{e_y} = 1,
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{e_x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$, $\mathbf{y},\mathbf{e_y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\mathbf{V}^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m},\forall i$ . And

\begin{align}
\mathbf{e_x} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \space\space 0 \space\space 0 \space\space \cdots 0 \end{array} \right]^T\\
\mathbf{e_y} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \space\space 0 \space\space 0 \space\space \cdots 0 \end{array} \right]^T
\end{align}

**My approach:**
Rewrite unconstraint objective Lagrange multipliers that take care of equality constraints

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\underset{\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}}{\text{minimize}} \hspace{4mm}  \big(\left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(1)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2 + \left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(2)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2\big) + \color{red}{\mathcal{v}_1}(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{e_x}-1) + \color{red}{\mathcal{v}_2}(\mathbf{y}^T\mathbf{e_y}-1)
\end{array}
\end{equation}

**Question**

1. IS this reformulation correct?
2. If yes, then how should I proceed with solving it.

Comment: 1. No, it's not correct. You don't even have Lagrange multipliers in there. 2. Why not just eliminate $y_1$ and $x_1$ altogether, to obtain an unconstrained problem?

Comment: if I eliminate these constraints won't I end up with the solution that you have proposed in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120402/constraint-minimization-of-sum-of-non-symmetric-matrices

Comment: I just missed those multipliers. I have edited my original post. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: I don't think that the problem makes sense. In most the case the minimum value would be zero. Simply pick some $x$ with $x_1 = 1$ then pick $y$ such that $y^T V^{(1)} x = y^T V^{(2)} x = 0$. Then scale $y_1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**$\color{red}{Partial Answer}$**
**Eliminating equality constraints**

Define following matrices for equality constraints

\begin{align}
\mathbf{A}_{2\times(n+m)} &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{e_x} \space\space \mathbf{0}_{1\times n}\\
\mathbf{0}_{1\times m} \space\space \mathbf{e_y}
 \end{array} \right], \space \mathbf{z}_{(n+m)\times 1} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{x}\\
\mathbf{y}
 \end{array} \right],\space \mathbf{b}_{2\times 1} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
1\\
1
\end{array} \right]\\
\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}&=\mathbf{b}
\end{align}

Also, we need two more matrices $\mathbf{P},\mathbf{R}$ for the objective function such that $\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{y}^T$ and $\mathbf{R}\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{x}$

\begin{align}
\mathbf{P}_{(n+m)\times(n)} &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{0}_{(m\times n)}\\
\mathbf{I}_{(n\times n)} 
 \end{array} \right]\\
\mathbf{R}_{(m)\times(n+m)} &= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
\mathbf{I}_{(m\times m)} \space \mathbf{0}_{(m\times n)} 
 \end{array} \right]
\end{align}

With these definition, rewrite objective function as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\underset{\mathbf{z}}{\text{minimize}} \hspace{4mm}  \big(\left(  \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{P}V^{(1)}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{z} \right)^2 + \left(   \mathbf{z}^T \mathbf{P}V^{(2)}\mathbf{R}\mathbf{z} \right)^2\big) \\
s.t \hspace{10mm}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{b}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Which is in the same form as

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\underset{\mathbf{z}}{\text{minimize}} \hspace{4mm}  f(\mathbf{z}) \\
s.t \hspace{10mm}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{z}=\mathbf{b}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

and follow this method on slide 11-4  http://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsocoee364a/11EqualityMin.pdf  [image]

Comment: This does not work since $\mathbf{PV^{(i)}R}$ contains all zero columns.