# How do I prove that this objective function is not convex?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\underset{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m}, \mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}}{\text{minimize}}\hspace{4mm}  \big(\lambda_1\left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(1)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2 + \lambda_2\left(  \mathbf{y}^T V^{(2)}\mathbf{x} \right)^2\big) \\
\end{array}
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{V}^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $\lambda_1\geq \lambda_2\geq 0$. How do I prove that the objective function above is **not** convex?

Comment: It quite clearly is not convex. If I were to prove it, I'd compute the Hessian and show that it is not positive definite. It's a bit tricky though so I'm not inclined to try. But *why* do you need to *prove* it? After all, the reason we prove something *is* convex is so that we can exploit that convexity in practice. In contrast, *non*-convexity is not something to exploit, it's something to avoid. So unless you have reason to believe something is convex, the best practice is to just assume it is not and move on.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This means that my answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339088/minimization-involving-equality-constraints is wrong

Comment: What does that question have to do with this one? That question does not ask about convexity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it's not tricky if we consider the $m=n=1$ case with all constants equal to $1$. The objective expression becomes $2y^2x^2$. The Hessian of this expression is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 4y^2 & 8xy \\ 8xy & 4x^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
The determinant of this Hessian is $-48x^2y^2$, which is negative when both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, so it cannot possibly be positive semidefinite. Hence the objective function is neither convex nor concave.

Comment: Thank you. This means that even if I fix $x=1$, the determinant is negative for any non-zero $y$. So there is no conclusive way in which I can minimize this objective?

Comment: Well, no, if you fix $x$ it is convex in $y$ and vice versa. That does not help much if $m,n>1$ given the equality constraints in the previous question. You could try alternating projections perhaps.

Comment: Actually I am stuck with this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1339088/minimization-involving-equality-constraints . I did some transformation but its not working in CVX because my quadratic function now contains a singular matrix. Can you please comment on that question.

Comment: Your problem is not convex, it's that simple.