# If the determinant of Hessian is negative, what can we say about the matrix?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, determinant, hessian-matrix

This question is based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1341313) for the question [How do I prove that this objective function is not convex?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1341219)

---

> The objective expression becomes $2y^2x^2$. The Hessian of this expression is $$\begin{bmatrix} 4y^2 & 8xy \\ 8xy & 4x^2 \end{bmatrix}$$ The determinant of this Hessian is $-48x^2y^2$, which is negative when both $x$ and $y$ are nonzero, so it cannot possibly be positive semidefinite. Hence the objective function is neither convex nor concave.

---

I don't understand the last line of this answer where author says "Hence the objective function can is **neither convex** nor **concave**." In other words, can someone fill in these blanks ?

If determinant of hessian matrix of $\mathbf{A}$ is

1. POSITIVE, $\mathbf{A}\in S^{N}_{++}$ and objective function is CONVEX
2. ZERO, $\mathbf{A} \in$ ___ and objective function is _________
3. NEGATIVE, $\mathbf{A} \in$ ___ and objective function is _________

Comment: The fact that the determinant is positive does not imply that the matrix is positive definite, and hence that the function is convex.

Answer (score 0):

Hint for 3: What is the opposite of convex?

Hint for 2: If a point is neither convex nor concave, it must be convex in one direction and concave in another (or flat).

Comment: Yes exactly. But then I am confused about the posted answer. It says **negative determinant**, matrix not $S^{N}_{+}$ and function is neither concave nor convex. It should be "CONCAVE", as you just suggested. RIGHT?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right, they're saying that since for any values of $x, y \neq 0$, the determinate is negative, there is no way that the hessian evaluated at any of these values is positive definite.

Comment: right. So basically we have $det \leq 0$ because $x,y \in R$. If $x=y=0 \rightarrow det=0$, we are in NEITHER/NOR case (this is not relevant to original optimization problem). If $x\neq 0,y\neq 0 \rightarrow det<0$ it is CONCAVE case

Comment: The trace of this matrix is $\ge0$ unless $x=y=0$, so at least one eigenvalue must be positive, therefore the matrix is neither positive nor negative semidefinite away from the origin.